# Foreign Key relations in Django, with a select condition

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I've a table of partner type

```
PartnerType
Name
Description
RelatedToProject
```

I've a PartnerMaster

```
Name
Address
PartnerType
```

I've a Project Table

```
Name
Partner (from partner master)
```

The partner in the project table has to be only of those types who have RelatedToProject = True

How can I achieve this in the model definition itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with Django, but you may want to consider removing the `RelatedToProject` field and adding another class called `PartnersRelatedToProjects` (or something like that). Then simply set up a normal foreign key from this new class to the `Partner` table, and in the `Project` class set up a normal foreign key to this new table.

You would then need to keep track of which partners are related to projects by adding them to the new `PartnersRelatedToProjects` table.

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PartnersRelatedToProjects(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey('Partner')

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    partner = models.ForeignKey('PartnersRelatedToProjects')
```